# Three desperados

Tags: probability

Three desperados A, B and C play Russian roulette in which they take turns pulling the trigger of a six-cylinder revolver loaded with one bullet. Each time the magazine is spun to randomly select a new cylinder to fire as long the deadly shot has not fallen. The desperados shoot according to the order A, B, C, A, B, C, . . .. Determine for each of the three desperados the probability that this desperado will be the one to shoot himself dead.

I have to calculate the probability that A dies at $i$th trial, so B and C never die. If at $1$th trial nobody dies we have $(\frac{5}{6})^3$. If at $i$th trial nobody dies we should have $(\frac{5}{6})^3+...+(\frac{5}{6})^3=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k(\frac{5}{6})^3$, because

$\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}[(A\cap B_1)\cup...\cup(A\cap B_k)]=\mathbb{P}(A\cap B_1)+...+\mathbb{P}(A\cap B_k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(A\cap B_k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(B_k)\mathbb{P}(A|B_k)$

and since $A\perp B_k\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\mathbb{P}(B_k)\mathbb{P}(A)=(\frac{5}{6})^2\frac{5}{6}+...+(\frac{5}{6})^2\frac{5}{6}=(\frac{5}{6})^3+...+(\frac{5}{6})^3=k(\frac{5}{6})^3$

where $A=[$A not die$]$. Thus A should die at $i+1$th trial with probability $\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k(\frac{5}{6})^3$.

Unfortunately the result is $\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{5}{6})^{3k}$. Why?

Comment: For starters... $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty k\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3$ diverges to infinity and so is clearly wrong.

Comment: @JMoravitz Right... So?

Comment: I'm trying to read your attempt to even understand what you thought you understood about this... so $A$ is the event that person A dies at all whenever it happened to be and $B_i$ was the event that nobody died during each player's $i$'th turns?  Why then do you think that $A = (A\cap B_1)\cup (A\cap B_2)\cup \dots$?  It isn't.  Why do you think that $(A\cap B_1), (A\cap B_2),\dots$ are disjoint?  They aren't.

Comment: @JMoravitz For the second property of partitions which provides precisely that the subsets $B_i$ are disjoint. So $A=A\cap \Omega=A\cap (\cup_{i=1}^{k}B_k)=A\cap (B_1\cup ... \cup B_k)=(A\cap B_1) \cup ... \cup (A\cap B_k)$

Comment: But $B_1$ isn't disjoint from $B_2$... the collection $B_1,B_2,\dots$ is not a partition of the sample space.  It is possible for noone to die during their first turns while simultaneously also noone died during their second turns so $B_1\cap B_2$ is nonempty.  Saying that noone died during their $2$'nd (*and the game is still continuing for them to even have second turns*) turns directly *implies* that noone died during their first turns either.

Comment: @JMoravitz In fact I don't understand how to apply $\mathbb{P}(\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(A_i)$ in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation is overly complicating the problem.  The probability that the gun first fires on the $i$-th pulling of the trigger is $(5/6)^{i- 1}\cdot(1/6)$... that is, the probability that the first $i-1$ trigger pulls don’t fire and then the $i$-th one does.  $A$ dies if this happens on the first, fourth, seventh, etc.... pulling of the trigger: if $i=3k+1$ for some natural $k$.  So
$$
P(A)=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{3k}=\frac{36}{91}.
$$
For completeness, since $B$ and $C$ require $i=3k+2$ and $i=3k+3$ respectively,
$$
P(B)=\frac{5}{6}P(A)=\frac{30}{91}
$$
and
$$
P(C)=\frac{25}{36}P(A)=\frac{25}{91}.
$$

Comment: @FrancescoTotti using boardgame terminology, note the difference between *rounds* and *turns*.  A round consists of each of our three players pulling the trigger (*noting that rounds can end early as soon as a live shot is fired*) whereas a *turn* consists of just a single player pulling the trigger.  The above work was in reference to the number of *turns* that have elapsed being $3k$ "safe" turns followed by a live shot (*turn counter having started from $1$*).  You could just as easily have worded this in terms of $k$ rounds passing... $\frac{1}{6}\left(\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3\right)^k$

Comment: @JMoravitz So, if it's true that $(\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{5}{6})\cdot ... \cdot (\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{5}{6})\cdot \frac{1}{6}=(\frac{5}{6})^3 \cdot ... \cdot (\frac{5}{6})^3 \cdot \frac{1}{6}= \frac{1}{6}((\frac{5}{6})^3)^k=\frac{1}{6}(\frac{5}{6})^{3k}$, why the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}...$?

Comment: We have only $\frac{1}{6} \prod_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{5}{6})^{3k}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz The only answer that I found (that is base on fact that the events are disjoint) is the Boole's inequality: $\mathbb{P}(\cup_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{5}{6})^{3k})\leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\frac{5}{6})^{3k}$

Comment: @FrancescoTotti because the events $A_0,A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots$ are a partition of the event $A$ where the event $A$ is that player A was the loser and the events $A_i$ were the event that not only was player A the loser but that player A specifically lost in round $i+1$ (*further implying that noone had lost at any time prior*).  Your earlier reference to disjoint events was in regards to $B_1,B_2,\dots$ which were not disjoint.

Comment: And we have that $A_i = \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{3i}\cdot \frac{1}{6}$ because for $A_i$ to occur we need that the previous $i$ rounds, i.e. the previous $3i$ turns, all to have ended with noone losing followed by A losing on their next turn.  The probability of this happening being the product you see

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem without any fancy series summing. You know that:

$$ P(A) = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6} P(C)$$

One time out of six, $A$ will lose right away. In the other $\frac{5}{6}$ of cases, $A$ will be in the same situation $C$ is at the beginning of the game.

Next you have:

$$P(B) = \frac{5}{6} P(A)$$

If A doesn't lose at the beginning, $B$ will lose with probability $P(A)$.

Of course you also have:

$$P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = 1 \; ,$$

since someone has to lose. You have 3 equations and 3 unknowns.